# What is the FQL equivalent of /posts on the graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to generate an alternate feed on my website that links to my (publicaly available) Facebook business page.

I want to select only posts made by the page (author) on Facebook, and no others. So I don't want the entire feed, just the equivalent of pressing the "...Page Title..." at the top of the Wall instead of "Everyone (Most recent)".

If I was making a direct graph call it would go:
https://graph.facebook.com/{$page_id}/posts?{$authToken}.

currently I have:

```
$queries = array(
  "stream"=>"SELECT post_id, created_time, message, action_links, attachment
  FROM stream
  WHERE source_id = 143019819074093
  ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 30",
```

It's probably something to do with filter_key, but I have no idea how this works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic case of solving your own problem minutes after posting the question:

Each post has both a source_id (the page it was posted on) AND an actor_id (the person who posted it). So, simply needed to add a WHERE actor_id = "XXXXXXXXXX" (page id number);

Genius.